# trying to round the average amount to 2dcp but when nesting, the round function returns an error

Tags: mongodb

the code without the round function is:

db.sales.aggregate([{$group: {
_id: '$item',
averageAmount: { $avg: { $multiply: ['$quantity', '$price'] } },},},
{ $sort: { averageAmount: 1 } },
])

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing round stage, please see example on the link

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hY3qZiH4FPc

Basically I just added addFields stage where the field is rounded

```js
db.sales.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      averageAmount: {
        $avg: {
          $multiply: [
            "$quantity",
            "$price"
          ]
        }
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      averageAmount: {
        $round: [
          "$averageAmount",
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      averageAmount: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not come across the $addfields before, very useful, I was trying to nest the round function in the group section.

Comment: Great, please mark question as resolved.